# No operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'B' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code. I'm trying to print the sum of two objects ints but the compiler gives me the following error:

```
binary '<<' : No operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'B' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I don't really understand what the error means. Why does it say the operator << needs a type 'B'. Isn't there a sum of two ints?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    protected:
        int x;

    public:
        A(int i) :x(i) {}
        int get_x() {
            return x;
        }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B(int i) :A(i) {}
        B operator+(const B& b) const {
            return x + b.x;
        }
};

int main()
{
    const B a(22), b(-12);
    cout << a + b;
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: Side note: Change it to a global function `B operator+(const B& b1,const B& b2)`, and declare it `friend` inside the class if needed.

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's why it's a side-note.

Comment: @barakmanos Why it *became* a side note :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Because I realized that the problem was with the `<<` operator and not the `+` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The `a + b` expression is using your custom operator - so it's as if you'd written (module constness - I'm just trying to get the flavour of what's going on):

```
B c = a + b;
cout << c;
```

That doesn't work because the compiler can't find a suitable `<<` operator with a `B` as the right operand - just as the error message says. It's worth asking yourself what you expected it to do with that.

If you want to print the value of `x` in the result, perhaps you want:

```
cout << (a + b).get_x();
```

Comment: `B` has a constructor taking `int`, so `int` can be converted to `B`

Comment: @M.M: Righto - will remove that last part. I'm not sure to conversions being *quite* that implicit :)

Answer (score 1):

Just overload the << operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const B& b)
{
    return out << b.x;
}
```

Comment: Better make it take a `const A&` and use `A::get_x()`.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `operator <<` definition to your `B` class. Something like

```
class B : public A {
    public: B(int i) : A(i) {}

    B operator +(const B & b) const { return x + b.x; }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & out, const B & obj) {
        out << obj.x;
        return out;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Can be done like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
        protected: int x;
        public: A(int i) :x(i) {}
                int get_x() { return x; }
};

class B : public A
{
public: B(int i) :A(i) {}
        B operator+(const B& b) const { return x + b.x; }
};

ostream & operator << (ostream &object,B &data)
{
    object << data.get_x();
    return object;
}

int main()
{
    const B a(22), b(-12);
    cout << (a + b);
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work (in standard C++). `a + b` is an rvalue. Can't bind to non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: So you can fix it by changing the operator to `ostream & operator << (ostream& object, const B& data)`, but note it may be better to use `ostream & operator << (ostream& object, const A& data)`